# what is purpose of structure declaration and definition here?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand how kernel code is written, following C basics.
I encountered that sometimes they do this, (fs.h)

```
struct backing_dev_info;
struct export_operations;
struct hd_geometry;
struct iovec;
```

I made a simple C program

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 struct bdinfo;
 struct bdinfo{
                int a;
                int b;
  };

 int main()
 {
  struct bdinfo var;
  var.a= 3 ;
  var.b = 5 ;
  printf("var.a = %d var.b = %d\n", var.a, var.b);
  return 0;
 }
```

It works. I need to understand, why struct **bdinfo** is written in this manner, or in fs.h file? What purpose does it serve in a program to write name of the struct at some place and declare it another place?

Answer (score 2):

This record

```
struct bdinfo;
```

is a declaration of a structure without its definition. It introduces a new type declaration in the given scope if it was not yet declared.

It can be used when the exact structure definition is unimportant. For example it can be used in function declarations

```
struct bdinfo f( struct bdinfo parm1, struct bdinfo parm2 );
```

or in pointer declarations. For example

```
struct bdinfo *p;
```

It makes a header more readable when details do not hide the main.

This record

```
 struct bdinfo{
                int a;
                int b;
  };
```

is a structure declaration and at the same time a structure definition. It is required when the exact structure definition is needed.

For example

```
struct bdinfo s = { 10, 20 };
```

This declaration requires that the structure definition would be known. Otherwise the compiler can not determine whether the initialization is correct or not.

Take into account that in the given scope there may be several structure declarations and only one structure definition. So you may write for example

```
 struct bdinfo;

 struct bdinfo{
                int a;
                int b;
  };

 struct bdinfo;
```

On the other hand if there is the following code

```
 struct bdinfo;

 struct bdinfo{
                int a;
                int b;
 };

 {
     struct bdinfo;
     //...
 }
```

then the structure declaration in the blcok scope declares a new structure that hides the declaration of the structure with the same name in the outer scope. They are different structures.

Comment: So if I declare the object in some .h file, and the programmer reads about it he may write another definition of it. So how it is useful? How readibility increases?

Comment: @Mlo Bootloader  Structure definitions can be very large. You can place a structure definition in a separate header. But other headers sometimes need to know that such a structure declaration exists that to declare for example a function. So they need onky the tag name of the structure that to declare the function.

Comment: So if a structure is needed locally, declaration is not needed. If the structure is used all over a project, we should declare it in some specific .h file and include that. That .h file should include that .h file which contains the definition of that structure. So in kernel, structure variables are declared, defined in this way?

Comment: @Mlo Bootloader This is not related to the kernel. It is a general approach to make the speed of the compilation higher limiting the sizes of compilation units. So if a structure definition is not needed in a module when why to include the whole header where it is defined?

Comment: @Mlo Bootloader Another reason is when you need to refer to a structure before its definition. In this case you can use a forward declaration of the structure.

Comment: Yes that can be the only reason. Use only those variables which are needed and include those defining files. Leave rest of them.

Comment: @Mlo Bootloader Also in this case you need not to recompile a module if the structure definition was changed because the module contains only the structure tag declaration. It does not refer to data members of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

It lets you hide the implementation if you want to. For example:

```
# foo.h
struct mystr;

struct mystr *foo();
int bar(struct mystr*);
```

.

```
# foo.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

struct mystr {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct mystr *foo() {
  struct mystr *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
  s->a = 1;
  s->b = 2;
  return s;
}

int bar(struct mystr *s) {
  return s->a;
}
```

.

```
# bar.c
#include "foo.h"

int main(void) {
  struct mystr *a = foo();
  return bar(a);
}
```

Here, `bar.c` is able to use pointers to `struct mystr` without actually knowing its definition.

Do note however that this is dependent on using pointers. If we had, for example:

```
# foo.h
struct mystr;

struct mystr foo();
int bar(struct mystr);
```

Then `bar.c` wouldn't be able to use `foo` and `bar`, since it would need to handle `struct mystr` objects, for which it needs to know the size of `struct mystr`, which it can't without knowing its definition.